# How quickly do experience orbs travel?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

An odd question, I know. I've scoured the internet and can't seem to get an answer, so I am asking here. For reasons I don't feel the need to disclose due to it being unimportant, I am trying to calculate how many blocks per second an experience orb travels on average. I've noticed that experience orbs pick up speed as they get closer to the player, but I'm asking for either a calculated median speed between the slowest and fastest speed, or both the slowest and fastest speed an orb of experience can go. I'm asking for both editions, so if the speed is different between them, mark what edition the speed is for.

In conclusion, **what is the average blocks per second that an orb of experience travels?**

Comment: I'm not sure you can calculate this. The orbs don't go at a constant rate of speed, but instead speed up the closer they are to the player. I have reason to believe that they might speed up linearly, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @OKprogrammer i would imagine you could dig through the code for it, but that might take a while.

Comment: This could be empirically determined by plotting the time to pick up an orb for a bunch of different distances; you'd need a contraption to catch some orbs and release them on command, while a player stands some distance away. The results might or might not produce a useful 'average blocks per second' value depending on what the behavior actually is, but they'd be an objective answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is given that the player's movement speed is 4.317 blocks per second and their `Motion`, which i used to test this, is 0.0784
This means that a `Motion` value of 1 would be 55.064 blocks per second.

That being said, I did some testing, and the velocity of an experience orb is roughly modeled by `-5.91561 * sin(0.19495 * x) + 5.89166` where x is the distance from the player

For the exact values, here's the graph I plotted: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5wgkjjukzl

It's somewhat difficult to get the exact 'average' speed as there is a falloff as the orb gets farther away and it is hard to find an exact endpoint where the xp orb no longer moves toward the player. 
This means that technically the slowest that the orb can move without being stopped is infinitesimally greater than 0.

There is also no real 'median' because the function is continuous, but if you want to know the speed when you are half way between the maximum and minimum distances, that would be 2.5935 blocks per second at the distance 3.05 blocks

### To answer your question

After some calculus, the average value of the function I defined earlier is 1.508 blocks per second. It won't be exact as the values I got didn't perfectly match the function but it's extremely close